# Random recursive function that stays near the initial value

Tags: functions, recursion, random, random-functions

I am working on a procedural CG scene and have populated a starry sky with particles of random size. My goal is to make the stars twinkle - in this case, by varying their size and/or alpha channels. The limitation of the software is that the only variables I can store per-particle are current size and current alpha - no initial states are preserved between frames. I can assign a function to each of these channels which effectively iterates over time: `alpha = f(alpha);`, `size = g(size);`

Another small detail, frames are integers only.

I am not experienced in this topic, but it is simple enough to create something pseudo-random, my first draft was `f(x) = tan(sin(f(x-1) + tan(f(x-1))));`

[Graph of the above function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlQqa.jpg) I cannot attest to its effectiveness, but it is a start.

This is all good, and after some tweaking can probably produce good-enough results, but there is one problem. I need my function to stay within a certain range of my initial value. So, if the initial size of the star was `i`, I would like it to stay within the `(i-r, i+r)` interval. So a big/bright star would stay big bright with some variation, and so would a small/dim star.

I am a little stumped. I would certainly appreciate a working example, but I would be very interested in learning how you would approach this problem in the first place, and what knowledge would be relevant. Thank you in advance.